# firebase - Angularfire (get posts of friend list)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a list of friends and a list posts, I'm trying to get all the friends of a user and then get all the posts of the friends.

In my component I'm getting the friends of a user and  then i am passing them to my service that trying to get the posts.

In component :_____________

```
ngOnInit() {

firebase.database().ref(`friends/status/${this.userUid}`).orderByChild('request').equalTo('accepted').on("child_added", snapshot =>{

const activeFriends = snapshot.val().friend;
console.log("friends", activeFriends);
this.feedDataService.findAllPosts(activeFriends)
.subscribe(
data => this.posts$ = data
);

})

}
```

This will return in console the ids of friends

friends Ste8mdpdjrUST6RQxbd4j7KAsFG2​

friends​ katwxN5JllYJ4PmzAoXnYygKrIg2​

I understand that this is because of "child_added" returned the 2 friends. If I had 30 friends I would get 30 console logs.

---

After I pass the activeFriends = snapshot.val().friend;​

My service___________

```
findAllPosts(activeFriends):Observable<FeedData[]> {

return this.db.list(`posts/${activeFriends}`,{
query: {
orderByChild: 'postTime'
}
}).map( (arr) => { return arr.reverse(); }).map(FeedData.fromJsonArray).do(console.log);

}
```

What in getting back in console log is the actual posts of this 2 friends that I have (the first user have 2 posts and the other 1 post), but I'm getting them  in different​ arrays because the keys I pass from them component triggers 2 times from child_added ( "see the logs up" )

[console log the arrays of posts of 2 friends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvF6B.png)

Now in my view I'm always see the last array of posts that have only 1 post

[The array I display in view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsw3A.png)

How can I combine the arrays,or how can i pass the friends keys with different way? Or how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `switchMap` and `combineLatest`. Using AngularFire, this would be something like:

```
this.postsByFriends$ = this.angularfireDatabase.list(`friends/status/${this.userUid}`)
  .switchMap(
    friends => Observable.combineLatest(
      friends.map(
        friend => this.feedDataService.findAllPosts(friend)));
```

`postsByFriends` should now be an observable of arrays, each element of which is posts by one friend. You could subscribe to it in a template with the `async` pipe.

[[NOT TESTED]]